# "A team" or "the team"?

Tags: articles

I would like to give thanks to my colleagues on the recent project. How to write correctly?

> Thank you for being **a** great team!

or

> Thank you for being **the** great team!

Comment: Using "the" or "a" depends on how many "great teams" there are in context. "the greatest team" would be ok because there would only be one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either will do (and will be appreciated).

"The great team" is a little stronger. It suggests (without explicitly claiming) "the greatest team" among all the teams, while "a great team" is one great team among many.

Comment: "...the great team" sounds wrong to me. It leaves me asking, "Which great team?", like, "*...the great team **that completed this project!*** Without such a qualification, it also suggests that the other teams are not great, which seems unnecessary in the context of thanking your team.

Comment: @gotube I agree that it's not literally correct. I wouldn't use it in a company wide announcement. But I can easily imagine saying it in a team meeting.

Comment: If something's not literally correct, please don't suggest it's correct to people learning English. The OP has accepted your answer which means they're likely using this questionable English after asking this question to make sure they didn't.

Comment: @gotube I understand the concern. I hope my answer suggests that I would say "the great" only in a colloquial informal setting, knowing that it was not correct. When the OP sees this comment they'll now that.